# Running Ext 4.0 and 4.1 on the same page using sandbox

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sandbox, extjs4.1

I know that using Sencha's sandboxing it's possible to have Ext 4 and 3 running on the same page without iframes. But is it possible to do the same with Ext 4.1 and 4.0 ?

Comment: what are the reasons for doing this?

Comment: I need to show on one page the differences in speed when running some custom code using both Ext versions.

Comment: hmm it looks like just loading ext-all + ext-all-sandbox will give Ext and Ext4 namespaces, which is enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loading ext-all + ext-all-sandbox will give Ext and Ext4 namespaces